# Firefox Add-On SDK - Opening link from pinned tab at end of tab list

Tags: javascript, tabs, firefox-addon-sdk

I am creating a customized homepage. I want to Pin the homepage tab (so it becomes small, also known as an app tab)

Now my problem is I have lots of tabs open, and links from Pinned Tabs open on the far left of the row of tabs. I want the links to open on the far right.

I tried the following code:

```
var tabs = require('sdk/tabs')
var pageMod = require('sdk/page-mod')

var mod = pageMod.PageMod({
    include: 'http://localhost/Homepage/',
    contentScriptFile: ['./jquery-2.1.4.min.js', './script.js'],
    onAttach: function(worker) {
        worker.port.on('URL', function(data) {
            tabs.open({
                url: data,
                onOpen: function(tab) {
                    tab.index = tabs.length
                }
            })
        })
    }
})
```

With this in `script.js`:

```
$('a').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    self.port.emit('URL', $(this).attr('href'))
})
```

This does not seem to work. The tab still opens on the far left.

I know that the tab is opening because of my `tab.open` because I removed it, and then clicking on the link did nothing

I also tried:

```
worker.port.on('URL', function(data) {
    tabs.open(data)
})
```

And using the original code but setting the `.index` to `999`, rather than `tabs.length`.

Are there any other methods to open a tab at the end of a tab list. If not, why is my code not functioning as expected?

Comment: Wouldn't the correct index for it be `tabs.length - 1` since this tab already exists?

Comment: That is what I thought. However, I tried `console.log` the index of a tab, each time one is opened. It seems (without any of my code), the new tab that opens on the far left *does* have an index of `tabs.length -1`. However, that should make it positioned on the far right?